# Avoiding webapp reload on screen flip

Tags: android, web-applications

I have a simple web app which opens my a simple website on the device:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("http://mysite.com");
```

The problem is that when i flip the phone screen into horizontal view and vice versa, 
the site (web application) is reloading.

How can i avoid that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Per default the application restart when the device orientation changes. Read here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

I think the section "Handling the Configuration Change Yourself" might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, this article helped. Added 
    `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`
To the main activity activity tag in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function called OnConfigurationChanged() method to be specific.